# Error expanding contents in a div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to expanding the contents of a div by not defining a specific height. Now, the contents are expanding alongside the div but the display is not okay because the background image is showing up instead of being covered by divs. How do I resolve this? Find attached image. [image]

> HTML CODE

```
<div class='user_container'>
                <div class='user_sec_teams col-md-4'>
                    <div class='inner_sec'>
                     <ul>
                <span class='points'> Title: </span> {$result['title']}</br>
                <span class='points'> Description: </span> {$result['description']}</br></br>

                <li class='button1' style='color:#A52A2A;'> <a href='' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#{$result['id']}' class='' style=' text-decoration:none; color:#A52A2A;'>Delete Thread</a></li>

                <li class='button2' style='color:#DC143C;'><a href='viewcircle.php?id={$result['id']}' style='text-decoration:none; color:#DC143C;'>View Thread</a></li>    
                     </ul>
                    </div>
              </div>
    </div>
```

---

> CSS CODE

```
.user_container{
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 130px;    
}
.user_sec_teams{
width: 350px;
height: 0px;
font-family: TimesNewRoman,Times New Roman,Times,Baskerville,Georgia,serif;
font-size: 15px;
padding-left: 10px;
background: #fff;   
}
.inner_sec img{
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 height: 70px;
 width: 70px;
}
.inner_sec img{
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin:5px;
}
.inner_sec p{
    background: #eee;
}
.inner_sec ul li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    left:0;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.inner_sec ul{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.inner_sec button{
    color: #fff;
    background:deepskyblue;
    outline: none;
    width: 12%;
    height: 3%;
    border: 1px solid deepskyblue;
    border-radius:27px;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #ccc; 
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: georgia;
}
.inner_sec button:hover{
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 3px #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you are using bootstrap's grids.! These grids the holds the property of float, which make them arrange next to each other.!

As per code, `<div class='user_sec_teams col-md-4'>` three DIVS arrange next to each other.! one more thing is; "Floated elements wont care about the height.' So, when you are using floated grid, you should specify height for proper arrangement.!

You have given fixed height but

- actual issue, you are stating is background image is showing up..!

For this, provide a background-color for parent & use clearfix after three `<div class='user_sec_teams col-md-4'>`..

Add below line for providing a clearfix
`<div class="clearfix"></div>`

> So your code should look like

```
<div class='user_sec_teams col-md-4'></div>
<div class='user_sec_teams col-md-4'></div>
<div class='user_sec_teams col-md-4'></div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class='user_sec_teams col-md-4'></div>
<div class='user_sec_teams col-md-4'></div>
<div class='user_sec_teams col-md-4'></div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

> THEN, CSS property

Please provide background-color for the parent instead of `<div class='user_sec_teams col-md-4'>` itself.

Comment: If accepted, make it as accepted answer. So, it will be helpful if some lands here